# How do I get a mesh to look like the clothing is griping onto it?

Tags: mesh

I tried using shapekeys and scaling but because they use vertexes I can't get it to work correctly. does anyone have any tips?

The stockings lay on top of the mesh but doesn't look like it its actually griping the mesh. Do I need to edit the topology or is there another way
[image]

[image]

This is the result I'm trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need to recreate is what's happening to the thigh skin when it's a little bit squeezed by the stockings : There's a kind of bulge just over the stockings line, then you could make the stockings radius slightly smaller than the thigh one, as if they were compressing the leg.

[image]

Comment: @moonbots thank you, I think it works. after that do I then subdivide it for smoother results?

Comment: you need to test, as long as adding edge loops doesn't seem to improve the result, don't add any. It looks like your mesh uses already enough edge loops, if not too much. Subdivision Surface modifier is another thing though, as it only adds virtual edge loops, but generally you don't need to go further than 2 subdivisions.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help.

Comment: and also, to smooth, don't forget to press the Smooth Shading button in the T panel (on the left of your 3D View)  ;)